# uploading images with Multer React.js and Node.js without using FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a CRUD application and already have mydata in the useState hook. I prefer not to change it to use formdata just for image upload. I want to use the useState hook for the image {imgUrl} as with my other states

This is the file page I'm using to upload the image.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import { createListing } from '../features/listings/listingSlice'
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner'

function CreateListing() {
// eslint-disable-next-line
const [geolocationEnabled, setGeolocationEnabled] = useState(true)
const { user,isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
 type: 'rent',
 name: '',
 bedrooms: 1,
 bathrooms: 1,
 parking: false,
 furnished: false,
 location: '',
 offer: false,
 regularPrice: 0,
 discountedPrice: 0,
 imgUrl:'',
 latitude: 0,
 longitude: 0,
})

const {
 type,
 name,
 bedrooms,
 bathrooms,
 parking,
 furnished,
 location,
 offer,
 regularPrice,
 discountedPrice,
 imgUrl,
 latitude,
 longitude,
} = formData

const navigate = useNavigate()
const isMounted = useRef(true)

useEffect(() => {
 if (isMounted) {
     if(user){
       setFormData({ ...formData, userRef: user._id })
     }else {
       navigate('/sign-in')
     }
   
 }

 return () => {
   isMounted.current = false
 }
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [isMounted])

const onSubmit = async (e) => {
 try{
   const listingData={
     ...formData,
   }
  
   
  console.log(listingData)
   dispatch(createListing(listingData))

   toast.success('Listing saved')
   navigate(`/profile`)
 } catch(error){
   toast.error('Could not add new listing')
 }

 
 
}

const onMutate = (e) => {
 let boolean = null

 if (e.target.value === 'true') {
   boolean = true
 }
 if (e.target.value === 'false') {
   boolean = false
 }

// Files
if (e.target.files) {
 setFormData((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState,
   imgUrl: e.target.files,
 }))
}

 // Text/Booleans/Numbers
 if (!e.target.files) {
   setFormData((prevState) => ({
     ...prevState,
     [e.target.id]: boolean ?? e.target.value,
   }))
 }
}

if (isLoading) {
 return <Spinner />
}


return (
 <div className='profile'>
   <header>
     <p className='pageHeader'>Create a Listing</p>
   </header>

   <main>
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <label className='formLabel'>Sell / Rent</label>
       <div className='formButtons'>
         <button
           type='button'
           className={type === 'sale' ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'}
           id='type'
           value='sale'
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           Sell
         </button>
         <button
           type='button'
           className={type === 'rent' ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'}
           id='type'
           value='rent'
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           Rent
         </button>
       </div>

       <label className='formLabel'>Name</label>
       <input
         className='formInputName'
         type='text'
         id='name'
         value={name}
         onChange={onMutate}
         maxLength='32'
         minLength='10'
         required
       />

       <div className='formRooms flex'>
         <div>
           <label className='formLabel'>Bedrooms</label>
           <input
             className='formInputSmall'
             type='number'
             id='bedrooms'
             value={bedrooms}
             onChange={onMutate}
             min='1'
             max='50'
             required
           />
         </div>
         <div>
           <label className='formLabel'>Bathrooms</label>
           <input
             className='formInputSmall'
             type='number'
             id='bathrooms'
             value={bathrooms}
             onChange={onMutate}
             min='1'
             max='50'
             required
           />
         </div>
       </div>

       <label className='formLabel'>Parking spot</label>
       <div className='formButtons'>
         <button
           className={parking ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'}
           type='button'
           id='parking'
           value={true}
           onClick={onMutate}
           min='1'
           max='50'
         >
           Yes
         </button>
         <button
           className={
             !parking && parking !== null ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'
           }
           type='button'
           id='parking'
           value={false}
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           No
         </button>
       </div>

       <label className='formLabel'>Furnished</label>
       <div className='formButtons'>
         <button
           className={furnished ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'}
           type='button'
           id='furnished'
           value={true}
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           Yes
         </button>
         <button
           className={
             !furnished && furnished !== null
               ? 'formButtonActive'
               : 'formButton'
           }
           type='button'
           id='furnished'
           value={false}
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           No
         </button>
       </div>

       <label className='formLabel'>Address</label>
       <textarea
         className='formInputAddress'
         type='text'
         id='location'
         value={location}
         onChange={onMutate}
         required
       />

       {!geolocationEnabled && (
         <div className='formLatLng flex'>
           <div>
             <label className='formLabel'>Latitude</label>
             <input
               className='formInputSmall'
               type='number'
               id='latitude'
               value={latitude}
               onChange={onMutate}
               required
             />
           </div>
           <div>
             <label className='formLabel'>Longitude</label>
             <input
               className='formInputSmall'
               type='number'
               id='longitude'
               value={longitude}
               onChange={onMutate}
               required
             />
           </div>
         </div>
       )}

       <label className='formLabel'>Offer</label>
       <div className='formButtons'>
         <button
           className={offer ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'}
           type='button'
           id='offer'
           value={true}
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           Yes
         </button>
         <button
           className={
             !offer && offer !== null ? 'formButtonActive' : 'formButton'
           }
           type='button'
           id='offer'
           value={false}
           onClick={onMutate}
         >
           No
         </button>
       </div>

       <label className='formLabel'>Regular Price</label>
       <div className='formPriceDiv'>
         <input
           className='formInputSmall'
           type='number'
           id='regularPrice'
           value={regularPrice}
           onChange={onMutate}
           min='50'
           max='750000000'
           required
         />
         {type === 'rent' && <p className='formPriceText'>$ / Month</p>}
       </div>

       {offer && (
         <>
           <label className='formLabel'>Discounted Price</label>
           <input
             className='formInputSmall'
             type='number'
             id='discountedPrice'
             value={discountedPrice}
             onChange={onMutate}
             min='50'
             max='750000000'
             required={offer}
           />
         </>
       )}

       <label className='formLabel'>Images</label>
       <p className='imagesInfo'>
         The first image will be the cover (max 6).
       </p>
       <input
         className='formInputFile'
         type='file'
         id='images'
         onChange={onMutate}
         max='6'
         accept='.jpg,.png,.jpeg'
         multiple
         required
       />
       <button type='submit' className='primaryButton createListingButton'>
         Create Listing
       </button>
     </form>
   </main>
 </div>
)
}

export default CreateListing
```

I added "multipart/form-data" in the header in the createlisting function in my listingService.js file as I read it is required

```
// Create new listing
const createListing = async (listingData, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'content-type': `multipart/form-data`,
    },
  }
  console.log({listingData})
  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, listingData, config)

  return response.data
}
```

Following the documentation, I added Multer in my listingRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' })

const {createListing, getListings, getListing} = require('../controllers/listingController')




const { protect } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware')

router.get('/', protect, getListings)
router.post('/',upload.single('imgUrl'),protect, createListing)
router.get('/:id',protect, getListing)


module.exports = router
```

For you guys to get the full picture, here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const colors = require('colors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
const cors = require('cors')

// Connect to database
connectDB()

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.json({message: 'Heloo'})
})

// Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))
app.use('/api/listings', require('./routes/listingRoutes'))

app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

Here is my createlisting function in my listingController.js

```
const createListing = asyncHandler(async (req,res) =>{
    const { bathrooms,bedrooms,discountedPrice,furnished,imgUrl,latitude,longitude,location,name,offer,
        parking,regularPrice,timestamp,type,userRef } = req.body

    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)
    
    if (!user){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('User not found')
    }

    

    const listing = await Listing.create({
        bathrooms,
        bedrooms,
      discountedPrice,
      furnished,
      imgUrl,
      latitude,
      location,
      longitude,
      name,
      offer,
      parking,
      regularPrice,
      timestamp,
      type,
      userRef: req.user.id
    })


    console.log({listing})
    console.log(listing)
    if (listing) {
        res.status(201).json({
          _id: listing._id,
          name: listing.name,
          message: 'House has been aded'
        })
      } else {
        res.status(400)
        throw new error('Invalid listing data')
      }
        
})
```

The issue is imgUrl is saved as imgUrl:"[object FileList]" in mongodb and no image is saved in the upload folder. This is my first time using Multer and every documentation/tutorial I have seen uses the formdata interface

Comment: `const { ... imgUrl ... } = req.body`

Please read documentation

Comment: See my comment, try to fix these things and then use postman to test just api if it will work then we will se frontend part

Answer (score 0):

First of all see documentation

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

You have

```
router.post('/',upload.single('imgUrl'),protect, createListing)
...
const { bathrooms,bedrooms,discountedPrice,furnished,imgUrl,latitude,longitude,location,name,offer,
        parking,regularPrice,timestamp,type,userRef } = req.body
```

Secondly file type looks like that (probably you are interested in `buffer`)

```
interface File {
    /** Name of the form field associated with this file. */
    fieldname: string;
    /** Name of the file on the uploader's computer. */
    originalname: string;
    /**
     * Value of the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header for this file.
     * @deprecated since July 2015
     * @see RFC 7578, Section 4.7
     */
    encoding: string;
    /** Value of the `Content-Type` header for this file. */
    mimetype: string;
    /** Size of the file in bytes. */
    size: number;
    /**
     * A readable stream of this file. Only available to the `_handleFile`
     * callback for custom `StorageEngine`s.
     */
    stream: Readable;
    /** `DiskStorage` only: Directory to which this file has been uploaded. */
    destination: string;
    /** `DiskStorage` only: Name of this file within `destination`. */
    filename: string;
    /** `DiskStorage` only: Full path to the uploaded file. */
    path: string;
    /** `MemoryStorage` only: A Buffer containing the entire file. */
    buffer: Buffer;
}
```